# how to select specific row by a column

Tags: r

I have a data, as an example I show below

```
a = rep(1:5, each=3)
b = rep(c("a","b","c","a","c"), each = 3)
df = data.frame(a,b)
```

I want to select all the rows that have the "a"

I tried to do it with

```
df[df$a %in% a,]
```

Can someone give me an idea how to get them out?

```
df2<- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), V2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("B02", "B03", 
"B04", "B05", "B06", "B07", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", "C06", 
"C07"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

I want to select specific rows that start with B but not all of them and just 02, 03, 04, 05

```
1   B02
1   B03
1   B04
1   B05
2   B02
2   B03
2   B04
2   B05
```

I also want to have the original data without them too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to check the 'b' column

```
df[df$b %in% 'a',]
```

For the updated question with 'df2', we can use `paste` to create the strings 'B02' to 'B05' and use `%in%` to subset

```
df2[df2$V2 %in% paste0("B0", 2:5),]
```

Or another option is `grep`

```
df2[grep("^B0[2-5]$", df2$V2),]
```

Comment: @nik IN that case, use grep, i.e. `df[grep('a\\.\\d*', df$b),]`

Comment: a01 a02 a03 a04 ..... I used like this but did not work ` df[grep(''a\\0\\*', df$b),]`

Comment: @nik Earlier you said that it is  `a.1, a.2` etc.  So, if you have a different pattern then just `df[grep('a\\d*', df$b),]`

Comment: do you know how to remove those rows from the original file too ?

Comment: @nik  You just need to update the original object i.e. `df <- droplevels(df[df$b %in% 'a',])`  I wrapped with `droplevels` as the 'b' column is `factor` and just by subsetting it won't remove the unused levels.  droplevels make sure that you have only the levels that are in the subset data

Comment: thanks but this will remove everything `df <- droplevels(df[df$b %in% 'a',]) `

Comment: @nik  What do you meant by everything.   It is only keeping the rows that have 'a' in 'b' column

Comment: I will ask another question in a minute so that you can get the credit for it too

Comment: @nik If you want to remvoe the 'a' rows from the original data, then `df <- droplevels(df[!df$b %in% 'a',])`

Comment: @nik I think the comment above should answer your problem.  Also, you can use `split` to convert it to a `list` of two data.frames. i.e. `lapply(split(df, df$b %in% 'a'), droplevels)`

Comment: this `lapply(split(df, df$b %in% 'a'), droplevels)`does not work because it is with numbers , for example can you check it on the updated example data I gave ?

Comment: @nik I already updated the post based on your updated dataset.  The `split` was based on the earlier data

Answer (score 2):

```
> df
   a b
1  1 a
2  1 a
3  1 a
4  2 b
5  2 b
6  2 b
7  3 c
8  3 c
9  3 c
10 4 a
11 4 a
12 4 a
13 5 c
14 5 c
15 5 c
```

This basically says:
For all columns in df choose rows that have value equal to a

```
> rows_with_a<-df[df$b=='a', ]
> rows_with_a
   a b
1  1 a
2  1 a
3  1 a
10 4 a
11 4 a
12 4 a
```

> 